# How Reading value from websocket using Golang

Tags: json, go, websocket

Im new to Go and I am connecting to a Stock Trading Websocket and my response log looks like this
`map[data:[map[p:111.95 s:AAPL t:1.599838531053e+12 v:1]] type:trade]`
How do I access the inner values?
My code looks like

```
    var msg interface{}

    // map[data:[ DATA ] type:trade]
    //DATA === map[p:117.18 s:AAPL t:1.599684492829e+12 v:200]
    for {
        err := w.ReadJSON(&msg)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(msg)
    }
```

Sample JSON
`{ "data":[{"p":7296.89,"s":"BINANCE:BTCUSDT","t":1575526691134,"v":0.011467}], "type":"trade" }`

if i add `map[string]` to the interface i am able to access the data slice by doing `msg["data"]`, but when i do `msg["data"][0]` to access the slice, i get a compiler error.

Im a go noob so i apologize if its a stupid question

Comment: @iLoveReflection post fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the question comments suggest, declare a Go type matching the structure of the JSON document:

```
type Message struct {
    Data []struct {
        P float64 `json:"p"`
        S string  `json:"s"`
        T int64   `json:"t"`
        V float64 `json:"v"`
    } `json:"data"`
    Type string `json:"type"`
}
```

Unmarshal to a value of that type:

```
for {
    var msg Message
    err := w.ReadJSON(&msg)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(msg)
}
```

Access fields using selector and index expressions:

```
fmt.Println(msg.Data[0])
```